# Set affected rows in resultset from stored procedure

Tags: mysql, resultset

I'm using the latest version of MySQL.
I wrote a Stored Procedure that performs three UPDATE statements.

Now, what I would like to have returned is a ResultSetHeader with the number of "affectedRows" set to the total number of updated values. On Google, I can't find anything about setting this during the stored procedure though.

I've been able to "SELECT @RowCount" but this adds a normal object to my return statement. I would like to have this value just be in the "affectedRows" without needing any additional data. See below code on how I made my statements. The variable @rows is what I would like to return as "affectedRows".

The number of rows updated during one of my tests is 4, but as you can see in my returned object, I get only the last UDPATE statement's affected rows.

```
# Previous code blocks removed

  UPDATE `Column` SET `Index` = 999
    WHERE `Id` = ColumnId;
    SET @rows = ROW_COUNT();
  UPDATE `Column` SET `Index` = IF(NewIndex < OldIndex, `Index` + 1, `Index` - 1)
    WHERE (NewIndex <= `Column`.`Index` AND `Column`.`Index` < OldIndex)
      OR (OldIndex < `Column`.`Index` AND `Column`.`Index` <= NewIndex)
    ORDER BY IF(OldIndex < NewIndex, `Index`, -`Index`);
  SET @rows = @rows + ROW_COUNT();
  UPDATE `Column` SET `Index` = NewIndex
    WHERE `Id` = ColumnId;
```

My returned object (in JS):
[ResultSetHeader { fieldCount: 0, affectedRows: 1, insertId: 0, info: '', serverStatus: 2, warningStatus: 0 }](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4c4hb.png)

Object when adding `SELECT @rows`:
 [{ @rows: 4 }, ResultSetHeader { fieldCount: 0, affecctedRows: 1, insertId: 0, info: '', serverStatus: 2, warningStatus: 0 }](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDCWJ.png)

-- EDIT --
Removed code unrelated to the issue.
Improved some information provided

Answer (score 0):

Plan A:  End with

```
SELECT @rows AS "affectedRows";
```

Plan B:  Change "@rows" to "@affectedRows", then that variable will be available outside the SP.

Be aware that the "resultset" of a Stored Procedure is an array of resultsets, one from each of the individual statements.  You have not specified the client language; I know, for example, that a PHP client requires special code to pick apart the pieces of that list of resultsets.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still only creates a new object. Logging what I receive results in:
```
  [
    [ { affectedRows: 4 } ],
    ResultSetHeader: {
      fieldCount: 0,
      affectedRows: 0,
      insertId: 0,
      info: '',
      serverStatus: 2,
      warningStatus: 0
    }
  ]
```

While my goal is to have the result:
```
  ResultSetHeader: {
    fieldCount: 0,
    affectedRows: 4,
    insertId: 0,
    info: ''.
    serverStatus: 2,
    warningStatus: 0
  }
```

Comment: I've slightly updated my question, hopefully this is a bit more clear now.

Comment: @ScrapsPrograms - What is your client language?  The "object" you presented feels like the "array" I added to my Answer.

Comment: I'm using the mysql2 library in NodeJS, but this just receives what the database returns. I could of course use the value received in Object form, but would prefer for it to be the ResultSet response value. Plenty of work-arounds, really. Just my stubborn mind wanting it one way and none other.

Comment: I've tried accomplishing my desired result using transactions but it seems this just returns 0 affectedRows. Odd behaviour on commit.

Comment: Another thing I'd looked into is trying to put all UPDATE statements into one, but there's a UNIQUE constraint on "Index" blocking it from executing. If you know a way of putting it all together into one, then the problem should also be solved.